# gtk3+ intercepting mouse click on frame

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

i just want to intercept mouse click on a frame, tried this code but don't work don't know why, i tried to click with all mouse button but no response:

```
__author__ = 'karim'

from gi.repository import Gtk


def tata(event, data):
    print('tata')

win = Gtk.Window()
win.set_title('test')
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.connect('button-press-event', tata)
win.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

but when i tried to bind **enter-notify-event** that has worked, when my mouse enter the 
**win** region, the console show me the message **tata** :

```
__author__ = 'karim'

from gi.repository import Gtk


def tata(event, data):
    print('tata')

win = Gtk.Window()
win.set_title('test')
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.connect('enter-notify-event', tata)
win.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

so why its don't know its not not working ??

Comment: Have a look at this question. Might be the event mask missing http://askubuntu.com/questions/157290/how-to-draw-on-mouse-click-in-gtk-drawingarea-using-pygi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation on [button-press-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) says:

> To receive this signal, the GdkWindow associated to the widget needs
>   to enable the GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK mask.

So import Gdk as well and then do

```
win.set_events (Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
```

That should make your example work.

In the text you also mention a frame. If you plan on doing the same thing with a GtkFrame note that only widgets with their own window can receive events, and containers like Frame typically do *not* have a window. You may have to put the frame inside a EventBox that can receive the events.